# tx fee (5274661132.35 ether) exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether) Web3 JS

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, bsc

New to web3 JS. using Binance Smart Chain (mainnet) :(

I am getting this error:

```
tx fee (5274661132.35 ether) exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether)
```

Below are my parameters (done on php for some reason, then sent to the browser):

```
                                           'nonce'    => '0x' . dechex(($nonce + 1)),
                                           'from'     => env('SENDER_ADDRESS'),
                                           'to'       => $address->address,
                                           'gas'      => 21000,
                                           'gasPrice' => 5000000000,
                                           'value'    => 2000000000000000, // I want to send 0.002 BNB
                                           'chainId'  => 56,
```

Am I doing anything wrong ?
I have put gasPrice and value in wei.